# Biztalk EDI 832 invalid character in data element

Tags: biztalk, edi

I have faced the problem when receiving edi 832 feed from partner:

> An output message of the component "Unknown " in receive pipeline "Microsoft.BizTalk.EdiInt.DefaultPipelines.AS2EdiReceive, Microsoft.BizTalk.Edi.EdiIntPipelines, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" is suspended due to the following error: 
>        Error encountered during parsing. The X12 transaction set with id '000000293' contained in functional group with id '293', in interchange with id '000000293', with sender id '8712423011011  ', receiver id 'WSAXXXXXXX ' is being suspended with following errors:
>   Error: 1 (Field level error)
>       SegmentID: PID
>       Position in TS: 16583
>       Data Element ID: PID05
>       Position in Segment: 5
>       Data Value: 
>       6: Invalid character in data element
>   .
>    The sequence number of the suspended message is 2.

I can't see which characters are invalid, by now I just know ",' will cause that problem. Then I tried to remove all characters which are not regular letter,number and common symbols may be invalid but still can't figure out which characters are invalid.

Which characters are invalid for EDI 832 and EDI 846 and others?

Comment: This depends on your TP/X12 settings...  Can you post the value of PID05 from an erroneous message?  Sanitized if need be

Answer (score 0):

The PID05 is Product Description.  There might be an asterisk or tilde in the data that is also a delimiter.  There could also be a non-displayable character such as a TAB which would also be illegal.

You should also download EDI Notepad and check it there.  If there is a character that breaks the EDI syntax rule, that (free) tool will identify it.